# Custom Query in Magento CE 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I made one more table in database which save sellers data then to load all seller's data I wrote following code and it is working like charm:

```
function getallSeller() {        
        $tableName = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName('Custom_sellerprofile');
        $model = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customerstatus', array('eq' => 1));
        $model->getSelect()->join(array('t2' => $tableName),"e.entity_id = t2.seller_id and t2.store_title!=''", array('store_logo' => 't2.store_logo',  'store_title' => 't2.store_title','description' => 't2.description','city' => 't2.city','store_title' => 't2.store_title'));
        return $model;
    }
```

after that I added one more attribute `REGION` in my custom seller's table   and then I want to fetch sellers by city(list of all sellers from particular region) for that I wrote this custom query but this is not working.

```
    function getSellerByRegion($region) { 
            $coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $connection = $coreResource->getConnection('core_read');

            $select = $connection->select()
                ->from( $coreResource->getTableName('Custom_sellerprofile'))
                ->where('region = ?', $region);

            $customers=$connection->fetchAll($select);
            $model = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customerstatus', array('eq' => 1));

            $model->getSelect()->join(array('t2' => $customers),"e.entity_id = t2.seller_id and t2.store_title!=''", array('store_logo' => 't2.store_logo',  'store_title' => 't2.store_title','description' => 't2.description','city' => 't2.city','store_title' => 't2.store_title'));

            return $model  }
```

getting this Error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query   was: SELECT `e`.*, `at_customerstatus`.`value` AS `customerstatus`, `t2`.`store_logo`, `t2`.`store_title`, `t2`.`description`, `t2`.`region` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
```

I guess that if we add that(custom) attribute in customer model then it can work but instead of that want to do from here only.

This is my first custom query so please don't hit much;)

Comment: `Custom_sellerprofile` is your table name in `config.xml` ?

Comment: yes @liyakat that is why all sellers details are fetching and I double checked it is there.

Comment: is `customerstatus` your custom customer attribute ?

Comment: error is in your `->join(array('t2' => $customers)` it should be your any table name like `->join(array('t2' => $coreResource->getTableName('Custom_sellerprofile')` and then add your rest of condition to it

Comment: @liyakat I did it already i will upload my solution soon and yeah your solution is very near. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

I did silly mistake which I figured it out after uploading my question.

Almost all things are okay here just need these little modification:

1. 1st do need to fetch data directly (so I removed this line code:)
   `$customers=$connection->fetchAll($select);`
2. So while joining put `$select` instead of `$costumers`